# One DataSource for multiple elements

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

is there any way I can configure a Kendo-UI DataSource for multiple elements (ListView, Grid, Charts) ??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You just need to use it there is no problem about sharing it.

Comment: This is the situation, the data coming back from the server, contains data for a listview, a grid and a chart, can I define 3 schema (one schema for each element)?

Comment: No, a data source can have only one schema.